# Is there room on the code "rebus" bandwagon for one more?

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle

```
public traverse(node)
  if (node == null)
    return
  traverse(node.left)
  visit(node)
  traverse(node.right)

public visit(node)
  //Look at node

public absurd()
  return 1/0

public main()
  traverse(node)
  try(absurd())
  catch(impossible)
```

This pseudocode represents a famous quote, what is that quote?

Comment: There's always room for more!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be

> "Only he who attempts the absurd is capable of achieving the impossible.", from Unamuno, <s>attributed</s> as a sort of response to Cervantes, *Sólo el que ensaya lo absurdo es capaz de conquistar lo imposible.*

To fit the rebus more precisely, though, we must use a misattributed variation of the quote:

> "In order to attain the impossible, one must attempt the absurd."
>  **Miguel de Cervantes**
>
>  This variation fits slightly better, per [@Mohit Jain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4637/mohit-jain)'s reasoning (the only difference being the "inorder" node traversal)

Comment: This fits well ... to a little less than half of the code. Is the tree-traversal stuff just a red herring?

Comment: I posted the original quote, which is apparently part of the intended answer. I've been literally underground since then, though

Comment: Sorry, I'm now feeling very stupid. Apparently how? (Is there some out-of-band discussion going on?) Underground for ... the 50 minutes between posting the answer and the comment? What does any of that have to do with the tree-traversal code in the question having nothing to do with the quotation? (For the avoidance of doubt, none of this is intended as complaint or criticism, and the Unamuno quotation fits half the question so well that it seems likely to be right. I'm just confused.)

Comment: @gareth ah, yeah, sorry - in the puzzles, etc. chat, the op indicated it was the right quote but missing something. I've just been on my way home in the time since so I've been unable to figure out which version of the quote is the one op is looking for

Comment: aha, understood.

Comment: I think Mohit Jain has figured out what the tree traversal has to do with it!

Comment: @gareth good for him, I guess. A shame it's not an accurate quote.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan OK, I've updated this post with the literal one word difference.

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer is:

> In order to attain the impossible, one must attempt the absurd.
>  **Miguel de Cervantes**

And the reason is:

> traverse(node) -> **[Inorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order)** traversal
>   try(absurd()) -> [Attempt](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=try%20synonym) the absurd
>   catch(impossible) -> Impossible ([attain is synonym of reach](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=reach%20synonym))

How did I find it:

> Search for the words "in order absurd impossible" on google and follow the [first link](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/m/migueldece161973.html).

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I think question_asker had enough of the answer prior to get accepted, +1 though

Comment: @GordonAllocman Thanks. Though I figured it out independently, I had no knowledge of the origin of quote and I relied completely on Google result.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly

> "Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth."
>  - Sherlock Holmes (Sir Arthur Conan Doyle)

But I'm not sure it matches that well...

Comment: Well, the code does look at what's left...

Comment: This seems to be almost the reverse of what's going on, though.